# Pusher Beams - push notifications unsubscribe not working in android

Tags: android, push-notification, pusher

I use Pusher Beams for my android app's push notification service. I want to make the app unsubscribe from all Pusher Beams push notification interests upon user's logout. I've tried this:

```
PushNotifications.unsubscribeAll();
```

I got no errors, but the notification still appears even when the user has already logged out. I've checked [Pusher Beams documentation](https://docs.pusher.com/beams) but there is nothing about `unsubscribe`.

As alternative, I'm using this code:

```
PushNotifications.unsubscribe("interestName");
```

It works, the only difference is that the latter needs specific interest name that will be unsubscribed.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<String> subscribes = PushNotifications.getSubscriptions();
for (String sub : subscribes){
    PushNotifications.unsubscribe(sub);
}
```

I did this. Hope it will help you. I also put this code before every subscribe just for case.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing alternatively, unsubscribing one by one using the interest name as what I wrote in the question. I wanted to use unsubscribeAll() to make things simpler but it does not work, that's what i wanna figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use
`PushNotifications.clearDeviceInterests()`  according to the documentation

https://pusher.com/docs/beams/reference/android/#cleardeviceinterests